# How to export a georeferenced TIFF for editing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, mapping

I've successfully plotted some points. See code and output.
I now want to save this as a .tif in order to add a base map like OpenStreetMap or Google Maps. How to?

```
pspcoord<-spTransform(plotcoord, CRS('+proj=utm +zone=21'))
plot(pspcoord)
```

[image: SpatialPoints]

Comment: writeRaster(r,'test.tif',options=c('TFW=YES')) > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257204/saving-geotiff-from-r

Comment: Why not save the points as a GeoPackage and load that into QGIS? Or use one of the mapping packages in R to add a basemap?

Comment: It looks like "plotcoord" is vector data. As tif is for raster data, something like a GeoPackage, KML, Shapefile would be more much more appropriate in that case. writeOGR() from the rgdal package can do that.